# after using pyinstaller systeminfo won't generate ouput

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, system-information

I am trying to run:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["systeminfo"],
                                      stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                      stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
file.write(output.stdout.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

In pyccharm this code runs fine and it will write the output to the file, but when I use:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole start.py
```

and run the generated .exe it is stuck at that part of my code. I can't find out why this is. I also use this for:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["netstat", "-aon"],
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
file.write(output.stdout.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

and:

```
output = subprocess.Popen(["arp", "-a"],
                                          stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                                          stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
file.write(output.stdout.read().decode("utf-8"))
```

These run fine and will write the output to the file.

If anyone knows a solution to this problem, please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It had to do with the encoding for me. After using:

```
sys_enc = locale.getpreferredencoding()
output = subprocess.run(["systeminfo"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, encoding=sys_enc)
file.write(output.stdout)
```

Everything works and it writes to the file ok.